# Installing LibFMP package in google colab

Tags: python, installation, package

I am always having problems installing packages. Not sure how to do it...
I'm using google colab and I'm trying to import LibFMP.

With these 2 commands, I get "E: Unable to locate package LibFMP"

```
!apt-get install LibFMP
!apt install LibFMP
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package LibFMP

With pip command, I get

```
!pip install LibFMP
```

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement LibFMP (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for LibFMP

Why is this so and how do I import the LibFMP? It happens a lot for other packages as well. It would be great if you can help in explaining when I should use which command to install the packages. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

LibFMP does not seem to be available via pip. LibFMP is included in [this zip file](https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/MIR/FMP/FMP_1.0.1.zip). I found it [here](https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/MIR/FMP/B/B_GetStarted.html).
I don't know how packages can be installed in Google Colab, but maybe you can upload the directory and install from source?

Maybe [this notebook about LibFMP](https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/MIR/FMP/B/B_LibFMP.html) also helps.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of the question, libfmp was not yet available on PyPi. This has changed in the meantime. You can simply install the package via pip, which also works in Google Colab.

```
!pip install libfmp
```

For more information, you can refer to

- the [documentation](https://meinardmueller.github.io/libfmp)
- the [Github page](https://github.com/meinardmueller/libfmp)
- the [FMP notebooks](https://audiolabs-erlangen.de/FMP)